# can't find snap7 library - linux

Tags: linux, python-2.7, raspbian, plc, snap7

I'm running Rapbian on a Raspberry Pi Revision B.

I downloaded the module python-snap7 as instructed on this webpage: [Snap7 Installation](http://python-snap7.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html)

I tried it twice: One time using pip and another doing it manually.
However, I installed it then via `setup.py build` and then  `setup.py install`.

If i try to create a client, I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import snap7
>>> c = snap7.client.Client()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7/client.py", line 29, in __init__
   self.library = load_library()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7/common.py", line 48, in  load_library
    return Snap7Library(lib_location).cdll
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7/common.py", line 40, in __init__
    raise Snap7Exception(msg)
snap7.exceptions.Snap7Exception: can't find snap7 library. If installed, try running ldconfig
```

I did the following after getting this error:

I added some lines to the file so it looks like the following:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
include /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7-full-1.2.1/
include /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7-full-1.2.1/release/Linux/ARMHF/Raspberry/
include /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7-full-1.2.1/src/lib/
include /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7-python/build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/snap7/
include /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7-python/
```

Then I issued the command `sudo ldconfig` to update the cache file `/etc/ld.so.cache`, but the error stays :(

1. Is it right to have the `include` instruction in fornt of each line?
2. Is there any kind of critical error I just don't see?
3. Which library do i need to include ?
   I just thought of the provided ones over here: [SourceForge Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snap7/files/1.2.1/). I have choosen the first .tar.gz package.

Sorry for my english and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you didn't install SNAP7 library (it's not included in python-snap7)

To use snap7 library on Raspberry Pi with python-snap7 wrapper you need to do followed steps:

1. Download SNAP7 library
   for example: `snap7-full-1.2.1`
   in Pi command line:
   `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/snap7/files/1.2.1/snap7-full-1.2.1.tar.gz/download`
2. Unzip downloaded file
   in Pi command line:
   `tar -zxvf snap7-full-1.2.1.tar.gz`
3. Compile library for raspberry (`arm_v6_linux.mk` is used for RPI 1. For RPI 2 use `arm_v7_linux.mk`)
   in Pi command line:
   `cd snap7-full-1.2.1/build/unix && sudo make -f arm_v6_linux.mk all`
4. Copy compiled library to `lib` directories
   in Pi command line:
   `sudo cp ../bin/arm_v6-linux/libsnap7.so /usr/lib/libsnap7.so`
   `sudo cp ../bin/arm_v6-linux/libsnap7.so /usr/local/lib/libsnap7.so`
5. (optional) Install python pip if you don't have it
   in Pi command line:
   `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
6. Install python wrapper for SNAP7 lib
   in Pi command line:
   `sudo pip install python-snap7`

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed snap7 library that is why you have this problem.

In order to solve this problem I suggest you to install it in a proper way. What I describe below is a horrible hacky way, but I have not found time to make better.

For a quick fix you can

- download this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/snap7/files/1.1.0/
- unar it, and
- in folder 'build/unix'
- run command `make -f x86_64_linux.mk all`
- then `cp ../../build/bin/x86_64_linux /usr/local/lib/`
- then modify common.py in order to manually point to your '.so' file in '**init**' function

I added this line at start of this function : `lib_location = "/usr/local/lib/libsnap7.so"`

Comment: This is not a very good answer. Per the documentation you can install Snap7 via pip. `pip install python-snap7`. However, even after installing Snap7 via pip you will get the error 'can't find snap7 library' with a line of code like `client = snap7.client.Client()`. But there is no error for the line `import snap7`, so it IS importing.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snap7
```

To give permissions to edit files in the `snap7` library directory.

Then edit the complaining files, below the init with an additional line like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    lib_location='/usr/local/lib/libsnap7.so' # add this line here
```